# The site does not contain a default keywords termstore?

Tags: mysite

In SharePoint 2010 - Mysites, the following columns show "The site does not contain a default keywords termstore" error:

Ask Me About
Past Projects
Skills
Schools
Interests

My research indicates that i need to check the default storage location check box in Managed Metadata properties, and i have, but the problem still persists.

What else can i do to solve this problem?

Comment: Is MMS service proxy associated with MySite? after checking default storage location if possible reset IIS

Comment: Not sure on the MMS service proxy. Where do i check that?

Comment: central admin>Application management > Manage Web Applications on this page click on web application from ribbon click on the service connection.

Comment: is it work now?

Comment: Yep, working good. Just needed to check the Manage Web Applications check box in Mysites service connections. Thanks once again!

Comment: I just added it as anwser for community benfit and get some vote for me as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks Like you have to make sure the Managed MetaData Services proxy associated with your MySite Web Application.

**To Check:**
central admin > Application management > Manage Web Applications on this page click on web application from ribbon click on the service connection.